# Is it possible to circle around the color spot on an image?

Tags: image-processing, color-detection

I'm doing an Image Processing Project. I'd like to circle around the yellow spot as follow.

[image: My Image]

How to know that position? I tried to find the value from image data (list), but I still don't know how to know that position and how to circle it.

Please help me.

Here is my sample code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.imread("img.jpg")
cap = cv2.resize(cap, (500, 500))

hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(cap, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Yellow color
low_yellow = np.array([21, 39, 64])
high_yellow = np.array([40, 255, 255])
yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_yellow, high_yellow)

yellow = cv2.bitwise_and(cap, cap, mask=yellow_mask)

cv2.imshow("Frame", cap)
test = cv2.imshow("Yellow", yellow)
cv2.imwrite("yellowSpot.jpg", yellow)

key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: You can find [contours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) and get the one with the largest [contour area](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html#:~:text=contour%20area).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using **GRIP** and its auto-generated code (it's a great GUI for building image processing functions in a graphical, easy-to-experiment way):

**My image processing "pipeline":**
[image: Pipeline]

**Image processing functions:**

1. Blur (to remove all the little noise spots from the image, and preserve the yellow spot)
   [image: Blurred_Img]
2. HSV threshold (to only show the YELLOW spot)
   [image: HSV]
3. Find Blobs (to find the yellow spots and put a CIRCLE around it)
   [image: Blob]

**Here is the [link](https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP/releases/tag/v1.5.2) to download the GRIP software**

**Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OHsJY_pq3eSrGvTbwXqktJryKwPP01uP?usp=sharing) to all my files (including the auto-generated Python image processing pipeline)**

Comment: Wow! That's great. Thank you so much.